# Asses significance in parameter differences in a multilevel model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

lets say I have a model hierarchical model. 15 Observation per Individual which are allocated in one of three Condition.

Observation| Individual | Condition

I have a single independent variable (IV) and want to predict my Dependent Variable (DV):
I include random slopes for Individuals and Condition.

**I would like to test whether the slope of two of the conditions is significantly differently from each other?**

Is that possible and if so How?

Here below is my model definition in terms of `nlme`:

```
lme(fixed = DV ~  IV, random =list( ~ IV|condition, ~ IV|Individual), data=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are fiting random intercepts for `condition`. Since you are interested in testing this variable, you should fit fixed effects for it. Moreover, with only 3 conditions, it doesn't make sense to fit random intercepts anyway since you will be asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable from only 3 observations. I would suggest:

```
lme(fixed = DV ~  IV + condition, random = ~ IV | Individual, data = data)
```

Then you will obtain fixed effects estimates for the intercept, which will include whatever level of `condition` is the reference level plus 2 estimates for the other 2 conditions which will be the difference between each of those estimates and the reference level.

Also, just a small point. You said :

> I include random slopes for Individuals and Condition

Actually you include random slopes only for `IV`

Comment: @Janosch Does this answer your question ? If so then please consider marking it as a the accepted answer and (if you haven't already) upvoting it. If not, please could you let us know why so that it can be improved